# __str__ from my own matrix, python

Tags: python, string, class, matrix

I'm making my own matrix module (I know that numpy exists) and I'm not quite sure how to build my `__str__`. My matrix looks like this

```
for _ in range(rows):
        self.matrixRC.append([2 for _ in range(colls)])
```

here I'm filling my matrix with the `int` 2. If we just say that `rows = 5` and `calls = 3` than i get this when i print it

```
[[2, 2, 2],[2, 2, 2],[2, 2, 2],[2, 2, 2],[2, 2, 2]]
```

but i want to get

```
222
222
222
222
222
```

does anyone know a simple 'Python' way to do this

This is literally the only part int the `__init__`

```
def __init__(self, rows = 10, colls = 10):
    self.matrixRC = []
    for _ in range(rows):
        self.matrixRC.append([2 for _ in range(colls)])
```

and for the `rows colls` thing... that was just weird thinking, I'm still having trouble thinking of this arbitrary matrix. But now the `rows and colls` should be done right. If it is easyer to make the `__init__` like this

```
def __init__(self, rows = 10, colls = 10):
    self.matrixRC = []
    for _ in range(colls):
        self.matrixRC.append([2 for _ in range(rows)])
```

than that's perfectly fine too

Comment: Could you post the code for the `matrixRC` class?

Comment: Indeed there is a simple way, your class code would be helpful.

Comment: Why don't you want separators between row items? Will they always be single digit numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the `str.join` method. The inner loop converts row items to string and joins them with the empty string as the separator, the outer loop joins the row strings with newlines.

```
class Test:
    def fill(self, rows, cols, val):
        self.matrixRC = [[val] * cols for _ in range(rows)]

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(''.join(map(str, row)) for row in self.matrixRC)

t = Test()
t.fill(5, 3, 2)
print(t)
```

**output**

```
222
222
222
222
222
```

---

If you decide that you *do* need a separator between row items, just modify the string of the inner `.join`, eg

```
'\n'.join(' | '.join(map(str, row)) for row in self.matrixRC)
```

gives us

```
2 | 2 | 2
2 | 2 | 2
2 | 2 | 2
2 | 2 | 2
2 | 2 | 2
```

---

Some people, including Guido, aren't fond of the `map` function. And it's actually more efficient to pass the `.join` method a list than a generator. So a more Pythonic version of that `__str__` method is:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '\n'.join([''.join([str(u) for u in row]) for row in self.matrixRC])
```

We could also make the code a little more readable by separating the two loops:

```
def __str__(self):
    out = []
    for row in self.matrixRC:
        out.append(''.join([str(u) for u in row]))
    return '\n'.join(out)
```

Comment: so your `fill` is a simpeler version of my `__init__` and your `__str__` joins the rows with `'/n'` and joins the items in those rows with nothing right?

Comment: @BrendanMesters I wrote that code while I was waiting for you to respond to my comments, before you posted your `__init__` code, but yes it does basically the same thing as your code. Yes, my `__str__`  joins the rows with `'\n'` and joins the items in those rows with the empty string.

Comment: @BrendanMesters We can safely do `[val] * cols` to make each row because `val` is an `int`, which is immutable. If `val` was a mutable object (eg a list), that wouldn't be safe, because `[val] * cols` makes a list containing `cols` references to the same `val` object.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning: `(map(str, row))` is equivalent to `(str(x) for x in row)`. IMO the slightly longer version is slightly easier to read.

Comment: @ArthurTacca Fair point. I've updated my answer. FWIW, I've been using `map` a lot lately, so I now find it more readable than the longer version. ;)

Comment: @BrendanMesters I've updated my answer with some variations that you may find easier to read.

Comment: It's also more efficient to write the whole thing in C (or assembler!). Personally I'd write it with a generator, which I consider simpler (but `map` is absolutely fine, I was just mentioning another option), and only use an actual list if it really turned out to be a problem